# Get actual type from array

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, reflection

Given this example:

```
IColor[] items;
items = new IColour[]{ new SomeColour() };
```

How do I use reflection to look at items, and get `typeof(SomeColour)` rather than `typeof(IColour)`? Using what i'm familiar with, `typeof(items).GetElementType()` gives me `IColour`, not the actual type.

Comment: Group all the item's type's (with GetType()), then get the least specific type.

Comment: @DeX3r: That wont even compile

Comment: typeof(items).GetElementType().DeclaringType off the top of my head so not  posting the as answer

Comment: @Zonder: Yours wont compile either, and you did not read the question.

Comment: @Bazzz It shouldn't give you anything because the `typeof` operator is syntax for a type literal, not a way to reflect the type of an object at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible. Your array can store multiple items, each having a different concrete type.

The type of your array is `IColor`. The type of the item stored at index 0, is `SomeColour`. What if you added a second item to the array: `AnotherColour`. What should be the type of `items`?

You can get the type of the items stored in your array by using `items[index].GetType()` where `index` points to the location in your array.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose the point of the answer then is that: 1) I can't do it on an empty array, 2) If I assume all elements in the array are the same concrete type, I get the type from the first element in an array, otherwise 3) I have to iterate over the entire array to get each item's type.

Comment: If you know that all elements are of the same type, you could also change the type of your array to a more concrete type. If your array would be SomeColour[], then SomeColour would be your array type. If you are not certain that all elements will have the same type, it follows that there is not one specific type for the whole array.

Comment: Oh certainly, but in this case I'm instantiating the container class, where each one has a different implementation of IColour, and I'm doing this reflection nonsense for the UI's sake (and it's Unity3D so it has certain quirks that don't allow me to get too fancy).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var t = item.GetType();
}
```

t should be SomeColur, OtherColur etc.

Answer (score 0):

`typeof(items).GetElementType` IS `IColor`, because it's a list of IColor.

To get a specific elements underlying type:

```
IColor item = items[<someIdx>];
item.GetType();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `IColor[]`, then the only thing you can say about the "actual type" is: `IColor`. For example, you could have:

```
class Foo : IColor {...}
class Bar : IColor {...}
```

and have an `IColor[]` array with 2 `Foo` and 3 `Bar`. Now: what is the "type" ?

If the array is non-empty, you could look at, say, the first item:

```
var type = items[0].GetType();
```

But that won't help if the data is heterogeneous. You could check for the *distinct* types and hope it turns out to be homogeneous:

```
var type = items.Select(x => x.GetType()).Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example of what @Wouter de kort is saying

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IColour[] items;
        items = new IColour[] { new SomeColour(), new SomeOtherColour() };

        Console.WriteLine(items.GetType().GetElementType().Name);  // Will always return IColour

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.GetType().Name); // Will return the name of type added with the IColour interface
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

internal interface IColour
{ }

internal class SomeColour : IColour
{ }

internal class SomeOtherColour : IColour
{ }
```